# How to use code sample into WordPress post?

Tags: html, content

I am using WordPress, and when I post some post data into my WordPress post, including some html code, as follows:

```
<code><div id="access"></div></code>
```

I want the code to be displayed, but the code is not displayed.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 3):

[Syntax Highlighter Evolved](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/) is the best plugin to use IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the `<` and `>` signs with their HTML entities:

```
&lt;div id="access"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
```

Now, the browser doesn't render the code inside of the `<code>` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin, [Preserve Code Formatting](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/preserve-code-formatting/), Wordpress will tend to strip some html tags.

Or you can character encode your html tags.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not display correctly and shows up as regular paragraph text. You would have to format the `<code>` property within your style sheet *if* it is not yet styled.

Here is an example

```
code {font-family:lucida console}
```